# ¿Como comprobar si existe una tabla con un mismo nombre en una base de datos con php?

Tags: php, mysql

¡Hola!,quisiera saber como puedo comprobar si existe una tabla con el mismo nombre con php , estoy haciendo una validacion para ver si existe , en caso de que existe no me haga nada y me envie un mensaje y en caso de que si me produzca la accion, pongo codigo :

```html
include "conexion.php";


$db->query('CREATE TABLE `daem' . date('Y') . '`
(
id int(240) auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(40) null,edad varchar(40) null,fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT pk_daem PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

'); // create table
$db->query('CREATE TABLE `salud' . date('Y') . '`
(
id int(240) auto_increment not null,
nombre varchar(40) null,edad varchar(40) null,fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT pk_salud PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

'); // create table

if ($db->connect_error) {
    echo "NO SE PRODUJO ya que existe una tabla ya creada con el mismo nombre";
} else {
    echo "Si se produjo";
}
```

Intente producir un connect_error  o un connect_errno Pero me indica que ya se produjo la accion osea que ya creo las tablas pero ya estan creadas ,de antemano Muchas Gracias!

(Editado)

Estoy usando mysqli y la variable $db es la variable de conexion

Comment: Solo puedes tener tablas del mismo nombre en bases de datos diferentes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748596/

Comment: No sabemos lo que hace ese handle `$db` que estas usando. No se si es PDO, mysqli u otra cosa, pero si esta consulta te devuelve algo entonces la tabla existe: `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'nombretabla'`

Comment: @masterguru   El $db es basicamente la variable de conexion , uso mysqli ,lamento no haberlo mencionado  , gracias! , Y abusando de su amabilidad ,podría concatenar una variable php a una sentencia sql? de esta forma :     $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `daem' . $anio . '`');  ? esto basicamente intento concatenar un valor de php a una sentencia sql pero resulta que esto no es válido ya que el $anio existe solo en php y no netamente en mysql , como podría seleccionar la tabla con un valor que me llegue y hacer la busqueda con el haciendo la concatenacion como se observo?

Comment: A ver, la consulta que dices no varia mucho de la que ya tienes en la pregunta, y que seguramente te funciona con el `date('Y')`.  Piensa que aunque sea mysql, lo estas lanzando desde PHP, y este sustituirá todas las instrucciones (como `date()`)  o variables de PHP (como `$anio`) que encuentre antes de lanzarla al servidor de base de datos.  Si no te funciona es porque `$anio` quizas no vale nada o no está bien asignado.

Comment: Si necesitas comprobar que determinada tabla o columna exista o no, entonces hay un problema de diseño. PHP no debería tener que comprobar esas cosas. Si de todas formas lo necesitas, se puede hacer desde SQL, `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`. Veo que estás creando tablas con nombre de fechas, error de diseño. Intenta normalizar tu data.

Comment: @masterguru Claro! , el tema es la varaible anio todo lo demas me funciona , resulta que anio es una variable enviado por post con un option de un select que me devuelve el año por ejemplo 2023 , y la idea es que pueda concatenar esa variable a una consulta sql para que me busque en las tablas el que tiene ese nombre concatenado por ejemplo salud2023(concatenado), pero ya que es una variable php y la consulta es sql , no me lo toma, desconozco si hay alguna forma de lograr que me propongo, de antemano , Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Crea una nueva pregunta con eso que estas diciendo, porque no tiene demasiado que ver con la actual, y pon en la misma el código que estas usando, tanto el PHP con la consulta del $anio, como el HTML con el select y el option y su form (y si usas javascript tambien, a ver si el problema será que usas ajax de forma incorrecta). Empiezo a pensar que estas bastante confundido con esto y mejor aclararlo en otra pregunta más específica con todos los datos.

Comment: @masterguru Gracias masterguru! Eso hare!!Gracias por tu tiempo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta viene derivada de otras que has hecho y creo que lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una tabla donde lleves un registro de los años creados, que te va a servir para mostrar el selector y para verificar que ya las tienes creadas, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `years` (
    `year` mediumint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `crated` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(`year`)
);
```

Cuando vayas a crear las nuevas tablas, creas un formulario y solo deja la opción para crear el siguiente periodo:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
// Por defecto, el año actual
$nuevoPeriodo = date('Y');
// Lees el último periodo guardado
$res = $db->query('SELECT `year` FROM `years` LIMIT 1 ORDER BY `year` DESC');
if($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Leer el último periodo
    $nuevoPeriodo = $row['year'];
}
// Incrementar año para el nuevo periodo
$nuevoPeriodo ++;
?>

<form method="POST" action="crearperiodo.php">
    <input name="nuevo_periodo" value="<?php echo $nuevoPeriodo; ?>">
    <button type="submit">Crear periodo</button>
</form>
```

Para procesar el formulario, revisas primero los permisos de usuario, suponiendo que solo el administrador puede crear nuevos periodos y también revisa que el periodo a crear sea el que corresponde:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";
// Aquí deberías verificar rol de usuario
// Por defecto, el año actual
$nuevoPeriodo = (isset($_POST['nuevo_periodo'])) ? $_POST['nuevo_periodo'] : date('Y');
// Lees el último periodo guardado
$res = $db->query('SELECT `year` FROM `years` LIMIT 1 ORDER BY `year` DESC');
if($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Leer el último periodo
    $ultimoPeriodo = $row['year'];
    // Validar
    if(($nuevoPeriodo - $ultimoPeriodo) != 1) {
        die('Los periodos deben ser consecutivos);
    }
}
// Aquí insertas el nuevo periodo en la tabla
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `years` SET `year` = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute([$nuevoPeriodo])) {
    // El registro se insertó correctamente
    // Aquí creas las tablas
}
```

En las consultas para crear las nuevas tablas solo remplaza `date('Y')` con `$nuevoPeriodo`. Si hiciste todo correctamente, no es necesario revisar si la tabla existe o no y, en todo caso, puedes agregar `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nombre_de_tabla ...
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! Esta muy completo!! Lo producire! Gracias por tu tiempo!!

Comment: Hola Triby! Quería consultarte algo , en temas de crear nuevamente las tablas tendría que ser así? $db->query('CREATE TABLE `daem' . $nuevoPeriodo . '`
    (
    id int(240) auto_increment not null,
    nombre varchar(40) null,edad varchar(40) null,fecha_registro TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT pk_daem PRIMARY KEY(id)
    ');  Se puede concatenar una variable php  en el nombre de la creacion de tabla?

Comment: Y en el $sql = "INSERT INTO `years` SET `year` = $nuevoPeriodo ";
 Tendría que ser asi tambien por casualidad?

Comment: @LuisCifuentes, 1. Sí, puedes usar la variable `$nuevoPeriodo` para crear las nuevas tablas. 2. No, porque se está usando una consulta preparada, primero `->prepare(consulta)` y después `->execute(arreglo_con_datos_de_remplazo)`, si lo quieres hacer directo con `->query()` entonces sí sería como planteas, pero estás expuesto a errores y riesgo de inyección SQL.